# How to handle dialog box contains close button only using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating one website it contains a "submit" button which opens a dialog box. In that dialog box I have to click on "update" button. But when the code clicked on "submit" button the next line of my code is not executing and not moving to open dialog box.
I have tried window handles, switch to alert methods but it is not working. Can anyone solve my issue?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: once the first button is clicked my code not even executing System.out.println(""); until i close the dialog box manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can achieve this with selenium since it's a security issue. However, after the click you can call an [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) exe that will find the button and click it:

```
ControlClick($CmdLine[1], $CmdLine[2], $CmdLine[3]);
//ControlClick ( "title", "text", controlID [, button = "left" [, clicks = 1 [, x [, y]]]] )
```

Another option is to use 'Robot' class in Java and send keys like enter to the alert once it's focused, e.g.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public void pressEnter(){

    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        logger.info("Could not create new Robot");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

}
```